# Как переделать код чтобы он соответствовал ООП MVC?

Tags: php, html, ооп, mvc

Данный код надо переделать в ООП MVC:

```
if (isset($_POST['length'])){


    $length = $_POST['length'];
    for($j=1;$j<=3;$j++){
        if ($_POST['opt' . $j] == 'on') {
            $checked_count+=1;
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['opt1']) && $_POST['opt1'] == 'on'){
        $boo = $length - ($checked_count - 1); $checked_count -= 1;
        $baz = rand(1,$boo);
        $num = str_shuffle($num);
        for ($i=0; $i < $baz; $i++) { 
            $pw .= $num[$i];
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['opt2']) && $_POST['opt2'] == 'on'){
        $boo = $length - $baz -($checked_count - 1); $checked_count -= 1;
        $baz = rand(1,$boo);
        $upper_alpha = str_shuffle($upper_alpha);
        for ($i=0; $i < $baz; $i++) { 
            $pw .= $upper_alpha[$i];
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['opt3']) && $_POST['opt3'] == 'on'){
        $baz = $length - strlen($pw);
        $alpha = str_shuffle($alpha);
        for ($i=0; $i < $baz; $i++) { 
            $pw .= $alpha[$i];
        }
    }
}
?>

<!-- VIEW-->
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
             <h3>Select Characters</h3>


             <input type="checkbox" checked="on" name="opt1"> Numbers without 0 and 1


             <input type="checkbox" checked="on" name="opt2"> Big letters without O and o


             <input type="checkbox" checked="on" name="opt3"> Small letters without "l"


             <h3 style="margin: 20px 0;">Password Length</h3>


             <input type="text" name="length" size="1" maxlength="1">


             <input type="submit" value="Generate">



            <div style="padding: 20px 0;">
                <div>Your Password:</div>
                <div style="width:200px; height:15px; border:1px black solid; font-size: 14px; font-family: monospace; padding:3px; color:#000; background-color: #D2E0E6; margin: 0;"><?php echo str_shuffle($pw) ?></div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Я даже не знаю с чего начать, ибо если я правильно понял правила MVC, то у меня не правильно так, как method находится в controller'е. Как переделать код чтобы он соответствовал ООП MVC?

Comment: Для начала я бы разобрался, что такое "соответствовать ООП MVC" и зачем вообще поставлена именно такая цель.

Comment: Что это за `boo`, `baz` и прочее? Может быть стоит сначала руку набить, а уже потом углубляться? Тем более, что с первого раза точно не поймете. И если рядом не будет никого, кто сможет исправить недочеты проектирования, то все будет еще хуже. Вообще - логика должна быть у вас в одном месте, отображение в другом, а то что будет их связывать можно считать контроллером. В интернете полно примеров (например, [у зенда](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)), но `не все то золото что блестит`. Особенно ссылка на `Skinny Controller` у зенда вообще вырубает

Comment: MVC имеет прямую связь с фреймыорками?

Comment: Скорее наоборот - фреймворки чаще всего реализуют поддержку MVC (иногда ее разновидности типа MVVM и прочие). Но при этом надо понимать, что поддержка со стороны фреймворка не гарантирует того, что у вас действительно будет MVC - он (фреймворк) не за вас же код писать будет

Comment: Спасибо. Это объясняет почему все туторы MVC связаны с фреймворками

Answer (score 1):

MVC - это разделение кода на три части.

M - модель, содержит или представляет данные и бизнес "правила". Эти данные передаются между контроллером и видом.
C - обрабатывает полученные HTTP запросы
V - отображение. Использует только данные модели, никакой бизнес логики.
Все части должны быть максимально независимы друг от друга.

#### Примерная схема его работы такова:

1) Пользователь передает запрос
2) Контроллер обрабатывает запрос
3) Выполняет операции с моделью
4) Выбирает представление для визуализации.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитать "Совершенный код" Маконела и привести в соответствие.

От себя:

1) Не доверяйте входных данным. Всегда проверйте их на корректность. $_POST['length'] может содержать вовсе не число, ав се что угодно.

2) У вас есть разные паарметры opt. Сделайте класс, который в зависимости от переданного параметра вернет объект, который выполнит обработку. Возможно все эти объекты стоит отнаследовать от общего класса, возможно, абстрактного.
Для примера:

```
$obj = ClassFactory::create($Opt)
$toView = $obj->proccessOptions();
```